# How to make multiple instances of logic app run?

Tags: azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I have been working with a Logic app which is URL triggered.

I am using an azure function which is timer based and is calling this logic app via PostAsync Call.

It can be possible that one instance of function at particular time can do multiple PostAsync With different IDs.

The issue I face is this:
Whenever my function is making multiple PostAsync Call with different Ids, Ideally the logic app should run multiple instances of it respective to those multiple IDs. But It is taking those calls sequentially. It would finish one instance and then would create new one for next ID and so on.

But If there's another instance of function running after few seconds, It would take it's request and process them simultaneously along with the first instance(one at a time similar to first instance).

What I want is, Irrespective of the instance of function weather it is same or not, logic app should create multiple instances for PostAsync calls.

PS: My logic app is configured to work in parallel mode by default.

Answer (score 0):

I test it in my side and it works fine, so I post my logic app and azure function here for your reference.

I created a logic app just contains two actions, shown as below screenshot:
[image]

Then I create a Httptrigger function in my azure function app, the code shown as below:

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System.Net;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net.Http;

public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(HttpRequest req, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

    request1(log);
    request2(log);

    return (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello world");
}

public static async void request1(ILogger log)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        log.LogInformation("do request111");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = client.PostAsync("http......", null);
    });
}

public static async void request2(ILogger log)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        log.LogInformation("do request222");
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        var response = client.PostAsync("http......", null);
    });
}
```

The function above includes two requests to request the logic app trigger, running this function and we can see two logic app instances are running at the same time in "Runs history" list on Azure portal.
[image]

Hope it would be helpful to your problem~

Comment: Tried this way. But Was unable to get the concurrency. :(

Comment: Hi @MaulikModi, could you please share the code in your function ?